# Error while building zephyr with cmake

Tags: compiling, cmake

im using ubuntu 18.04 and im getting this error while executing the first program helloworld

```
                                                                                                             CMake Error at /home/hp/zephyr/cmake/extensions.cmake:1082 (message):
 Assertion failed: The detected dtc version is unsupported.The version was found to be 1.4.5 But the minimum supported version is 1.4.6
```

Comment: That sounds like an error when *running*, rather than an error when *building* - you really have 2 options: upgrade your system to 18.10 which has [device-tree-compiler 1.4.7](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/device-tree-compiler), or build a newer version of dtc from source

Comment: What do you mean by Zephyr? Do you mean *"Project Athena's notification service"*. If you mean this, then it is already [packaged in Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=zephyr-&searchon=names) (both server and client).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

As steeldriver suggested, device-tree-compiler (dtc) is below the minimum version that zephyr requires. I faced a similar issue with my build and fixed it as follows:-

1. Get the latest stable version of [device-tree-compiler](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/device-tree-compiler) (check
   that it says current-stable and not active development). Currently
   it is 1.4.7-1.
2. Unzip the package:-

   ```
   tar xvf device-tree-compiler_1.4.7.orig.tar.xz
   ```
3. Install required dependencies:-

   ```
   sudo apt-get install flex bison swig python-dev
   ```
4. Navigate to the project directory and build the project:-

   ```
   cd dtc-1.4.7 && make
   ```
5. Replace the existing dtc with the latest installed. You can do this
   by updating your $PATH or moving the installed dtc to /usr/bin
6. Ensure that the default dtc is now the latest

   ```
   cd ~/ && dtc --version
   ```

This should return Version: DTC 1.4.7. After that, rebuild your HelloWorld program and it should be good to go.

I hope this helps.